# xampp perl and Multiclient socket programming

Tags: perl, sockets, xampp

I need to implement a multiclient tcp server. I am using xampp for web designing. And to run the socket program i use perl interpreter coming with xampp, Do i need to use thread or fork for this? I need some light overhere.
   
**UPDATED:** Since this web server is already multithreaded, Do we need to again use the multi thread concept? Or multi threading is supported only for web pages?

Comment: you probably need IO::Select - not fork or threads. However you may be want to fork several clients to speedup responses but IO::Select should be in core.

Comment: Thanks.I am using IO::Socket.